# How do I check if a StringVar in an Input is empty

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to make a button to create a file name with an input of a text variable, I'm trying to make an input that would be the "default" if the actual text box is empty, my code is as follows

```
def makefile():
    try: prefix_text.get()
    except NameError: prefix_text = None
    if prefix_text is None:
        prefix_text=StringVar()
        prefix_text.set("Kido")

    ply = open(prefix_text.get()+"_Player_.uc", "w")
    ply.close()

window=Tk()

l1=Label(window, text="Prefix")
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)


prefix_text=StringVar()
e1=Entry(window, textvariable=prefix_text, width=42)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)


b1=Button(window, text="Create File", width=12, command=makefile)
b1.grid(row=1, column=1)



window.mainloop()
```

MakeFile is supposed to test if the input is empty before making the file and if it is empty just set the name to be *Kido*, however this somehow will always cause the name to be *Kido* instead of the input

I've tried various things to no avail and nothing I can seem to find gives me good input on how to check if that variable is null, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Oh makes sense, then what would be there assuming I can't go directly to the if statement? or would I do .set there
Sorry sorta new to python

Comment: It seems like your code is confusing the `StringVar` instance itself for the *text contained within* that instance.

Comment: Wouldn't that be checking if it were null or not set? usually i would get an error about it being used before assigning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the entry is empty just check the linked variable `prefix_text`. Also be sure to use `prefix_text.get()` instead of just `prefix_text`.

```
def makefile():
    global prefix_text
    try: prefix_text.get()
    except NameError: prefix_text = None
    if not prefix_text.get().strip():   # if blank entry
        prefix_text.set("Kido")  # set entry
        
    ply = open(prefix_text.get()+"_Player_.uc", "w")
    ply.close()
```

Comment: Ahh I see, so rather than having it set a "new variable" it uses a global one and sets that in it's place, that definatly wouldn't be my first thought! huge thanks!

Comment: The `try / except` block can be removed as it is not necessary.